# Adding an Action Bar to the top and bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want bottom bar in application home page and top bar also what i can do for it

[image]

Comment: you can do it but should not do it. check [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

for create bottom tab bar
http://envyandroid.com/align-tabhost-at-bottom/

but be carefuller http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html said avoid to use bottom bar..

I hope this help you...

Comment: @how to give thanks , i give u lots thanks and lots vote thanks

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by using toolbars. You can use one as ActioBar and another one for a buttom bar.

Have a look here:http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html